# my html text is not displaying in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I'm getting nothing with this:

```
mainAns.htmlText = '<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">The differen <B>is</B></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>';
```

Maybe it has something to do with the quotes? the text will be retrieved from a database.
I dont see what I am doing wrong

EDIT:

I think it's the way I calculate the number of lines in the string... How would I calculate the amount of lines using rich text?

Comment: What do you mean by you're getting nothing?  Are you sure the component is added to a container?  Have you used the debugger to see the value of htmlText after you set it?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
mainAns.htmlText = ='<![CDATA[
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">The differen <B>is</B></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
]]>';
```

> How would I calculate the amount of lines using rich text?

why do you need this?